# Get progress of socket read operation

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I'd like to write little file transfer program in C (I'm working on Linux).
I'm quite new to sockets programming, but I already managed to write little server and
client programs.

**My question:**

If I have something like this:

`int read_bytes = read(socket_id, buffer, 4096);`

While reading from the socket, how can I get the progress of reading?
For example I want to display every 100ms how many bytes have been transferred
so far. I'm pretty sure I have to use threads or other async functions here.
Is there a function so I can get the `number of bytes read` and the `number of bytes to read`?

**Update 1:**
Accumulating read()

```
int total_read_bytes=0, read_bytes;
char buffer[4096];
do {
    read_bytes = read(socket_id, buffer, 4096);
    total_read_bytes += read_bytes;
} while(read_bytes > 0); /* Read to end or read failed */
```

Isn't this very, very inefficient? (For example to transfer a 1MiB file)

Thank you

Comment: You will need to count of many bytes are read from each call to `read/reicv` and report that to the total expected

Comment: You can granularize the reads, with smaller buffer sizes. This will be efficient or inefficient depending on the situation.

Comment: You can skip using threads if you make the socket non-blocking

Comment: @Asaf: that's not necessary for the requirements as given, as having recv return immediately when there's no data is not a situation where the on-screen total needs to be updated.  Krumia's suggestion doesn't help either, as recv will return (by default) when some of the data has been delivered, without blocking for more to arrive from the network.

Comment: @pentix: that code would burn CPU in non-blocking mode, but is generally efficient in blocking mode (you might consider a larger buffer size - e.g. 16k - but the general loop and logic is fine), but the termination needs to be `read_bytes > 0` to handle a -1 error return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control to the code of both the server and the client, you can let the sender to tell the receiver the size of the file before actually sending the file. For example, using the first 8 bytes in the message. That's the `number of bytes to read`.

By accumulating the `read_bytes` in your example, you can get `number of bytes read`

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "accumulating"?
You mean calling read() in a loop?

Comment: @pentix: Anyway you want: in a loop, as a class member varirable, etc

Answer (score 1):

Each `recv` call will block until it's read *some* more, but it won't (by default / sans `MSG_WAITALL`) wait for the supplied buffer to be full.  That means there's no need to reduce the buffer size in an effort to get more frequent updates to the total bytes read information, you can trivially keep a total of `recv()` return values that updates as packets arrive (or as fast as your app can process them from the OS buffers).

As you observe, if that total is being updated 100 times a second, you probably don't want to issue 100 screen updates, preferring to limit them to your 100ms min interval.  You could use a timer/alarm to manage that, but then you have more edge cases to see if the timer is already pending etc..  It's probably simpler just to use two threads where one checks periodically if an update is needed:

- thread1:

  - while ((n_bytes = recv(...)) > 0)

    - total_bytes += n_bytes;
  - set screen-updater-termination flag
- thread2:

  - last_total_bytes = -1;
  - while the screen-updater-termination flag's not set

    - sleep 100ms
    - if last_total_bytes != total_bytes

      - update screen
      - last_total_bytes = total_bytes

Of course you'll need to use a mutex or atomic operations to coordinate some of these actions.

> Is there a function so I can get... the number of bytes to read?

Not from TCP itself - it doesn't have a notion of message sizes, and the API just ensures an app receives the bytes in the same order they were sent.  If you want to be able to display a "N bytes received so far, X more expected", then at the application protocol level, the sending side should prefix the data in a logic message with the size - commonly in either a fixed width binary format (ideally using `htonl` or similar to send and `ntohl` on the recv side to avoid endian issues), or in a textual representation that's either fixed with or separated from the data by a known sentinel character (e.g. perhaps a NUL, a space or newline).

Comment: There's no need to introduce multiple threads or timers/alarms just to limit the rate at which screen updates are sent.  Instead, when recv() returns, just check the current time (via times() of clock_gettime() or some other milliseconds-or-better-resolution clock API) to see if more than 100mS have passed since the last time a screen-update was triggered.  If so, trigger another screen update; otherwise don't.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the need of `htonl`. I forgot about the network byte order.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: wrong - say the second `recv` returns 50ms after the first, and the third 10 second after that, using your approach the bytes read by the second `recv` wouldn't be immediately incorporated on screen because it's been less than 100ms since the first - only the 3rd `recv` would get things back on track.  With TCP there can be sudden spikes as a missing or delayed packet enables earlier-received but later-sequenced packets to be `recv`-ed.  Whether genuine accuracy in these matters is useful is debatable, but that's what the question asks for....

Comment: @TonyD so we're in agreement that if you don't need perfect accuracy, it would work.  And if you did need perfect accuracy, you could obtain that by using select() with a timeout argument and non-blocking I/O.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: it's not "perfect accuracy" - it's 100ms updates as per the question, and for some "I could be displaying stale data for an indeterminate amount of time" version of "work", sure.  Of course you could use select/poll with a timeout, or an alarm, or lots of OS-specific async alternatives, still - in my opinion a second thread is as good a choice as anything, so that's what I've documented.  If you prefer and want to answer with another approach, knock yourself out.